# Grails 2.4.4 request object logging

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I need to log the incomming REST request (xml).
So I create a

```
public class RequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

private String _body;

public RequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    super(request);
    _body = "";
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = request.getReader();
    String line;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
        _body += line;
    }
}
```

Now I use a filter to log out the incomming request:

```
class XmlogFilterFilters {

def filters = {
    all(controller:'*', action:'*') {
        before = {
            RequestWrapper wrappedRequest = new RequestWrapper(request)
            log.info(wrappedRequest.reader.text)
        }
    }
}
```

This logs the incomming request as expected.

But now in my controller the request is empty and cannot be used to Build my Domain-Object:

```
 class InquiryHandlerController {
  def save(Inquiry inquiryInstance) {
   ... *** inquiryInstance is null here
  }
 }
```

I guess the problem is, that th request was already read in the `RequestWrapper`, and therefor cannot be read again in the *magic requestToDomain conversion*.

So how can I pass the new `RequestWrapper Object` instead of the original `request` to the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution:

use grailsplugin: grails-httplogger in version 1.1 do the right wrapper thing, so logging and consuming is working now.
https://github.com/prumps/grails-httplogger